# Perform request using specific network interface

Tags: node.js, networking, request

Is it possible to perform GET/POST request in NodeJS using specific network interface?

I.e. with CURL I can invoke two POST calls like:

```
curl -X POST --interface wlan0 http://192.168.1.5/resource
curl -X POST --interface wlan1 http://192.168.1.5/resource
//                       ^^^^^
```

Both IP addresses are **different machines** - so first WiFi module is connected to one SSID, second is connected with a very different network, but the IPs are equal because of some top requirements (they lay in different, isolated networks).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the localAddress option in the `http` options:

- https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

You need to set it to your IP address that is used for a given interface.

Another option would be to use `node-curl`:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-curl

Comment: Thank you for the response. But what if both of the sub-networks will assign the same IP for my WiFi adapters?

Yeah, node-curl may be my second attempt, but I'd like to handle it in request-way somehow.